# What Encryption Method is this?

Tags: encryption, aes, reverse-engineering, xor

I am trying to reverse engineer the 3M50 Filtrete Thermostat (Server support is ending). The thermostat sends a request to a http server every 5 minutes. I used mitmproxy to listen to the request and saw that the request looked like the following :

```
{"uuid":"5cdad4dfaa2a","format_ver":"102","eiv":"2ab26c2e4e9407b790e86b8250f8c186"}\xb4&\xfbBX\x1a\x9aD\x99C\xee\xd4\xd7h\xf3Z\x01\x18\x8f\xe6\x94\xdeo &\x18OIxY'Z\x06*^\xf0\xa8\x9c#\x1a\xacK\xbb\x03\xdc\xaf*\xdc\xdf\xe0\xd8\xcd
7\xf7\x99\xc24\x06n\xa2\xac\xa9\x95\xc0\xbe\x86
\x8d\x03\x84G,\xa7uG\x80\xa6jK\xc5ZC\x11\x07h\xc1\xbe\xf7\x02\xbf\x8e\x83\xc2\xdf\xad\x99ha\x11\xa8\x8f7\x7f8\xff\x9b\x11%?\xbb\xb2k\xe15\xea$\xea4-x\xc1\x8bJT\xcbM\x8c\xfe\xc8\x84\x91,
51\xf9\xb1\x97\xd2\xbbCr\xf8w!\xfc\xd3\xa6\x08p\xce\xd9@\x17\xf7\x91"('5B\xf0\x18\xbe_V\x8b\xc7\x02\x8f\xfd\xbb\xd5N:\xcf\xa9J\x94\x0f9\xc3\xffBs\x87(\xe9\xae\x9e\x00\x9b\xc7\xe3\x0bZ,\x85\x9fc5e\x16\xea+\xba\x16^\xfe\x14\xce4\xe7b\x91\xbe;\x994\xa7W2\x1d\x03\xe7[\xf38\xa1\x19,\x84\xf8\xb8\xe5|\xa8\xb1\x00\x7f
G\xa2\xa4c^\\\x05\xf1\xdb\x08\xd5w\xed
hD\xdbC0\xd0\x98-}\x07\xa2\x14\xc8\xd7\x12\x06\x17\x9f_\xe8\x1b\x97]J\x82S`\xff\xee\xd7\xaa \xe7@K\x05\x0c\xc3!3\xa3W\xf0O\x89\x96w\x86
```

the response from the server was

```
\xbf\x8d\xb3\xba\xec"\xd2+\xe68\xb9\xc6\xe4z\x93=H]\x14\xb4\x1e\x83\xca\xe84\x1e\x1f\xc8\xf7\xbbp\xa6\xe6\xf2k\x18P\x129\xfcS\xae\x9e\xcek\xe6\x04\x08\xc1\xc7\x82Y\xd8\xa8\x13\x8b\x174]\x99\x1c\xe0;\xe8
```

I was like either base64 or some other encoding, ran it through CyberChef https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef, nothing came through.

The second thing I thought was that this was a java desarlized object. The server seems to be running Java from the http response headers. I then fetched the APK for radio thermostat (https://m.apkpure.com/wi-fi-enabled-radio-thermostat/RadioThermostat.com), and decompiled it looking to see if it many requests to the api endpoint and it didn't.

Looking some more I disassembled The microcontroller that the thermostat uses is PIC18F65J11. This shouldn't be running Java so I realized i was barking up the wrong tree.

Looking at the request again it seems an IV is sent (not sure if its encrypted or not) and the auth key that the thermostat uses is : "authkey":"c419f19f".

Looking at some docs here https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00953a.pdf, it looks like the pic18 micro-chip family uses AES, XTEA, SKIPJACK, or XOR.

I used https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef, with AES and XOR but i wasn't able to get anything of meaning.

I am at a loss now at what to try, I don't know of any algorithm that uses a 16 byte iv and a 4 byte key. I don't know if the eiv (Encrypted iv ? ) is a red herring, but any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're probably better off reverse engineering the stuff if the protocol isn't public domain. Just trying stuff at random is next to useless when it comes to cryptographic algorithms as most of them will produce randomized output.

Comment: It's unclear what that output is from but it looks like python's format for printing `bytes` objects, but without the surrounding `b""`.

Comment: I would not assume the "authkey" is an encryption key itself. Auth tokens can be used in many ways (it could be part of the key, or could just be an authentication header separate from encryption). I would expect there's a hard-coded shared key, so reverse engineering other clients does seem a fruitful approach. But take a look at this, for a polling solution for this thermostat: https://github.com/statusbits/smartthings/blob/master/devicetypes/statusbits/radio-thermostat.src/radio-thermostat.groovy

Comment: @RobNapier, thank you. So I have about 25 of these thermostats and I really liked not having to run a raspberry pi at each location to support them which is why I am attempting to do this and not going to go with the polling solution. When you mention a hard-coded-shared key, i thought it would be the auth key since this value is shared between the device and server at first connect and isn't sent in the payload anymore. When you say this "reverse engineering other clients "  do you mean looking at other thermostat requests and responses or something else?

Comment: I highly doubt the authkey is the actual key. As you suggest, 32-bit keys are not normal, and a custom algorithm that picked such a trivial key wouldn't also include a 128-bit IV. I'm sure the authkey is used for something else, or is just part of the key (or the key is derived from it, or something like that). I was just recommending that if there are other related apps (like the Android app you mention), they might include the same algorithm somewhere, so reverse engineering them might help you. SO isn't a reverse-engineering site, so this is really off-topic here, but best of luck with it.